# Oracle where clause compare date value with time value 23:59:59

Tags: sql, oracle, date, where-clause, date-format

Here is my query to fetch records :

```
select * from ProductTracker where EventDate >= TO_DATE( '01/01/2016','MM/DD/YYYY') 
                               AND EventDate <= TO_DATE( '11/18/2016','MM/DD/YYYY');
```

This query will give results from date 01/01/2016 to 11/18/2016 00:00:00
AS This query  will only work if the time is 00:00:00. TO_DATE with MM/DD/YYYY generates a date whose time is 00:00:00. So I won't get records whose date looks like 11/18/2016 11:50:00 PM
Any Way to get all results ?

Comment: Try using `<` rather than `<=`?  (Less than the 19th, rather less than or equal to the 18th.)

Comment: So... what do you want to include? Everything up to the current time? Then just use `<= SYSDATE`. Can the EventDate be in the future, and you want to catch everything from year 2016? Or what?

Answer (score 1):

First, use ISO-standard date formats.  Then you can do:

```
select pt.*
from ProductTracker pt
where EventDate >= DATE '2016-01-01' AND
      EventDate < (DATE '2016-11-18') + 1
```

You can also say `+ interval '1' day` if you prefer.

Comment: Up-voted for using ANSI/ISO date literals. P.s. no need for brackets e.g. `DATE '2016-11-18' + 1`

Answer (score 0):

You can just take where date is less than next day:

```
select * from ProductTracker 
  where EventDate >= TO_DATE( '01/01/2016','MM/DD/YYYY') 
    AND EventDate < TO_DATE( '12/18/2016','MM/DD/YYYY');
```

or use hour in format:

```
select * from ProductTracker 
  where EventDate >= TO_DATE( '01/01/2016','MM/DD/YYYY') 
    AND EventDate < TO_DATE( '11/19/2016 00:00','MM/DD/YYYY hh24:mi');
```

Comment: 'hh' must be either 'hh24' or 'hh ...  AM', and minutes should be 'mi'.

Comment: You should be using the 19th day of 11th month, not the 12th day of the 18th month.  You've misread his date format ;)

Comment: First of all I should write it more carefully ;) Thanks for fixes.

Answer (score 0):

### You can use trunc

`select * from ProductTracker 
where trunc(EventDate)  >= TO_DATE( '01/01/2016','MM/DD/YYYY') 
                               AND trunc(EventDate)  <= TO_DATE( '11/18/2016','MM/DD/YYYY')`

Comment: If you wrap a function around a search field you prevent any indexes on that field from being used.  Don't do this.

Comment: So you can use function index Ok?

Comment: That solves a problem you created yourself by using TRUNC.  So, just don't use TRUNC?  Instead of <= 18th, just use < 19th.

Comment: İf you select on EventDate many Times,  it should be like that

Answer (score 0):

below query worked fine:

```
Select * from ProductTracker where
 EventDate >= TO_DATE('01/01/2016','MM/DD/YYYY') 
AND EventDate < TO_DATE( '11/18/2016 23:59:59 ','MM/DD/YYYY hh24:mi:ss');
```

Thank u all for your qiwk response.